# Carrying over last known values without a loop in a matrix

Tags: r

This question is related to my earlier (solved) post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438481/filling-in-values-without-a-loop/32440559#32440559) where I was looking for a way to carry over the last known value in case of NA value using Base R due to speed concerns.

Different to then, I have a matrix now and not a column vector, and the method marked previously as solution does not work here. The data is in the data frame x:

```
x=data.frame(c("2015-05-31","2015-06-30","2015-07-31","2015-08-31"),c(NA,200,NA,NA),c(NA,NA,50,NA))
colnames(x)=c("Date","AAPL","IBM")
x[,1]=as.Date(x[,1],origin="1970-01-01")
x
  Date      AAPL IBM
2015-05-31   NA  NA
2015-06-30  200  NA
2015-07-31   NA  50
2015-08-31   NA  NA


index = !is.na(x)
x[,] = x[index][cumsum(index)]
x
   Date          AAPL IBM
2015-05-31 2015-08-31 200
2015-06-30        200 200
2015-07-31        200  50
2015-08-31        200  50
```

This wrong. The last known value of AAPL is carried over to IBM, and the last date to AAPL.

I would need

```
y
   Date           AAPL IBM
2015-05-31          0  0
2015-06-30        200  0
2015-07-31        200  50
2015-08-31        200  50
```

or

```
z
   Date           AAPL IBM
2015-05-31         NA  NA
2015-06-30        200  NA
2015-07-31        200  50
2015-08-31        200  50
```

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Update:

I believe the

```
index = !is.na(x)
x[,] = x[index][cumsum(index)]
```

would work if there was a way to replace each first occurence of NA by 0. The problem is that each NA can start in a different row (not necessarily the first as in the example).

Update2:

Thanks a lot for the numerous posts below. The solution to my particular case is straightforward as it is sufficient to replace each first row's NA by 0 (and not its first occurence):

inserting

```
x[1,is.na(x[1,])] = 0
```

in front of

```
index = !is.na(x)
x[,] = x[index][cumsum(index)]
```

will do the job:

```
   Date     AAPL IBM
2015-05-31    0   0
2015-06-30  200   0
2015-07-31  200  50
2015-08-31  200  50
```

I am still reluctant marking my own post as solution (although is solves the case).

Comment: Please remove the `>` signs for copying

Comment: If you don't want to use a package: Use `apply` to fill NAs columnwise. But I really suggest to reshape your data to long format and use package data.table or dplyr. Or, since this is a time series, use package xts and its `na.locf` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply your carry-forward operation over each vector of the data frame independently.  This requires either a `for` loop or an `apply` statement (effectively the same thing, but might be mildly optimized)

The following works and has your base R requirement:

```
x=data.frame(c("2015-05-31","2015-06-30","2015-07-31","2015-08-31"),c(NA,200,NA,NA),c(NA,NA,50,NA))
colnames(x)=c("Date","AAPL","IBM")
x[,1]=as.Date(x[,1],origin="1970-01-01")
x

base_locf <- function(y, na = NA){
  initial_na <- min(which(!is.na(y)))
  i1 <- !is.na(y)
  t <- y[i1][cumsum(i1)]
  if (is.na(y[1])) t <- c(rep(na, initial_na -1), t)
  t
}

as.data.frame(lapply(x, base_locf), 
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

as.data.frame(lapply(x, base_locf, na=0),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And while the `base_locf` appears to be faster than `zoo::na.locf`, I'm certain it is more robust and provides better responses to errors and problems in the code. (EDITED: uses a larger(ish) data set)

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(zoo)

DF <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10000),
                 y = rnorm(10000, 5, 3),
                 z = rnorm(10000, 10, 2.5))
set.seed(123)
DF$x[sample(1:10000, 500)] <- NA
DF$y[c(1, sample(1:10000, 1000))] <- NA
DF$z[sample(1:10000, 2000)] <- NA
microbenchmark(
  base = as.data.frame(lapply(x, base_locf),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  zoo = as.data.frame(lapply(x, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  zoo_plain = na.locf(DF, na.rm=FALSE),
  loop = for(i in seq_along(DF)) DF[[i]] <- base_locf(DF[[i]])
)

Unit: microseconds
      expr      min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval cld
      base  751.292  821.8170 1644.690  869.4695 1534.255 54234.95   100  a 
       zoo 1905.208 2040.3940 3657.343 2743.0080 3044.610 54669.54   100  a 
 zoo_plain 3697.224 4709.7970 6594.909 4994.0965 5316.079 62811.17   100   b
      loop  608.189  649.5365 1557.218  697.0420 1493.640 56144.26   100  a
```

And because I was curious what would happen with more missing values forced in

```
DF <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10000),
                 y = rnorm(10000, 5, 3),
                 z = rnorm(10000, 10, 2.5))
set.seed(123)
DF$x[sample(1:10000, 2000)] <- NA
DF$y[c(1, sample(1:10000, 4000))] <- NA
DF$z[sample(1:10000, 6000)] <- NA

microbenchmark(
  base = as.data.frame(lapply(DF, base_locf),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  zoo = as.data.frame(lapply(DF, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  zoo_plain = na.locf(DF, na.rm=FALSE),
  loop = for(i in seq_along(DF)) DF[[i]] <- base_locf(DF[[i]])
)

Unit: microseconds
      expr      min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval cld
      base  788.534  824.3100 1722.840  883.5450 1639.089 53433.80   100  a 
       zoo 1875.884 2080.4215 4233.562 2722.4800 2925.405 60464.04   100  ab
 zoo_plain 3683.735 4741.4670 6600.050 4961.8400 5207.432 62354.59   100   b
      loop  636.634  679.7405 1661.977  743.0815 1525.017 60177.84   100  a
```

Comment: Are you benchmarking a 4 rows data set? Also, how `x[-1] <- na.locf(x[-1], na.rm = FALSE)` compares against your solution (on a bigger data of course).

Comment: fair point.  I didn't think that through.  Give me a few minutes to put together a big data set and I'll update.

Comment: But you don't need `lapply` for `na.locf`.

Comment: User 10,000 rows for the edit, but still admittedly not a very complicated data set.  I still suspect `na.locf` will fail more gracefully, and has the benefit of a few other bells and whistles.  I'd consider it a much safer bet than my chicken scratch code.  But I'm not sure @DavidArenburg what you have in mind for comparing `x[-1] <- na.locf(x[-1], na.rm=FALSE)`.  I don't see why that would behave differently.

Comment: oh..That I didn't know (that I dont' need `lapply`).  I'll give that a shot---and after editing, I might still use `lapply` with `na.locf`.